# Shorthand way of allowing null and undefined as parameters

Tags: typescript

Is there a shorthand way to tell TypeScript that a parameter can be `null` and `undefined` maybe even just allow any `falsy` value?

I can do this, but it doesn't accept null as a parameter

```
function a(b?: string | number) {}
```

I can do this, but then the function definition length starts to get long when you have multiple parameters.

```
function a(b?: string | number | null) {}
```

Comment: Make a type alias and use it?  `type Nullable<T> = T | null | undefined`, `function a(b?: Nullable<string | number>)` ?

Comment: `?` works only with `undefined` because it mirrors how optional parameters work in ES6. If you explicitly pass `undefined` to a parameter with a default value in ES6, it will still evaluate the expression after the `=` in the parameter list. Whereas, if you pass `null` or another falsy value to a parameter with a default value, that value will stick rather than evaluating to the default expression.

Comment: Okay thanks, It looks like I will have to go with creating a type as @jcalz suggests